# QString function for only alpha characters?

Tags: qt, qstring

I am newbie in QT(4.7.4) and I am search for function, that checks an QString for alpha-characters and returns "true" if in this QString contains only characters.
Should I write this simple function myself? :( I hope it exists such function as isText() in VBA, but in Google and documentation I have not found it.

Thanks for answers and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply validate the string with a QRegExp class matching an alphanumeric string. I suggest to use it with QValidator to be more clear.

Comment: I have done it with help of regular expressions: 'QRegExp rx("[A-Z]|[a-z]*"); if( rx.exactMatch(Name) ) {....}'thx a lot! Its simpier, than write new function!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (If your goal is to accept only strings, which contains a single character):

```
bool containsOnly(QString str, QChar c)
{
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        if(str.at(i)!=c)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

and in use:

```
bool b = containsOnly("String", 'a');
```